# Only one of my drop-down menus is able to open (New to HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML, CSS, JS, and am trying to replicate a simple website with multiple drop-down menus. I followed a tutorial to create a single drop down that seems to work pretty well. But I'm not sure how to duplicate this into a second drop-down menu, as when I keep the variables the same, it does not open. And when I simply add a "2" to all the variables and try and make it a completely separate element, it also does not open. THe javascript is the main thing I am having trouble understanding. Any guidance on a more efficient way to do this would be greatly appreciated it!

```js
const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

const selected2 = document.querySelector(".selected-2");
const optionsContainer2 = document.querySelector(".options-container-2");
const optionsList2 = document.querySelectorAll(".option-2");

selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
});

optionsList.forEach(o => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");

    });
});

selected2.addEventListener("click", () => {
    optionsContainer2.classList.toggle("active");
});

optionsList2.forEach(o => {
    o.addEventListener("click", () => {
        selected2.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
        optionsContainer2.classList.remove("active");

    });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Century Gothic";
}
body {
    background: #D6DFEB;
}
h2 {
    margin: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #011C49;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
p {
    color: #011C49;
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.container {
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #EFF1F4;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 430px;
    border: 1px solid #C8C8C8
}
.select-box {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.select-box .options-container {
    background: #D6DFEB;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    max-height: 0;
    width: 28%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    order: 1;
}
.selected {
    background: #D6DFEB;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    color: #011C49;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    order: 0;
    background-color: #D6DFEB;
}
.selected:after {
    content: "";
    background: url("arrow-down-grey.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 75%;
    width: 32px;
    right: -5px;
    top: 3px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.select-box .options-container.active {
    max-height: 240px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
}
.select-box .options-container.active + .selected::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    top: -2px;
}
.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    background: #0d141f;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #525861;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.select-box .option,
.selected {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-box .option:hover {
    background: #414b57;
}
.select-box label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-box .option .radio {
    display: none;
}
.select-box-2 {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.select-box-2 .options-container-2 {
    background: #D6DFEB;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    max-height: 0;
    width: 28%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    order: 1;
}
.selected-2 {
    background: #D6DFEB;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    color: #011C49;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
    order: 0;
    background-color: #D6DFEB;
}
.selected-2:after {
    content: "";
    background: url("arrow-down-grey.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 75%;
    width: 32px;
    right: -5px;
    top: 3px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.select-box-2 .options-container-2.active {
    max-height: 240px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
}
.select-box-2 .options-container-2.active + .selected-2::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    top: -2px;
}
.select-box-2 .options-container-2::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    background: #0d141f;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.select-box-2 .options-container-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #525861;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.select-box-2 .option-2,
.selected-2 {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-box-2 .option-2:hover {
    background: #414b57;
}
.select-box-2 label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-box-2 .option-2 .radio {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <title>Travel Website</title>

    <link href="CSS-FirstWebsite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Find the best deals on flights right now</h2>

<div class="container">
    <p>Leaving from...</p>
    <div class="select-box">
        <div class="options-container">
            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Australia" name="category"/>
                <label for="Australia">Australia</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Japan" name="category"/>
                <label for="Japan">Japan</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Africa" name="category"/>
                <label for="Africa">Africa</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="France" name="category"/>
                <label for="France">France</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="China" name="category"/>
                <label for="China">China</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Brazil" name="category"/>
                <label for="Brazil">Brazil</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Argentina" name="category"/>
                <label for="Argentina">Argentina</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Norway" name="category"/>
                <label for="Norway">Norway</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="selected">
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>Going to...</p>
    <div class="select-box-2">
        <div class="options-container-2">
            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Australia*" name="category"/>
                <label for="Australia">Australia</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Japan*" name="category"/>
                <label for="Japan">Japan</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Africa*" name="category"/>
                <label for="Africa">Africa</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="France*" name="category"/>
                <label for="France">France</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="China*" name="category"/>
                <label for="China">China</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Brazil*" name="category"/>
                <label for="Brazil">Brazil</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Argentina*" name="category"/>
                <label for="Argentina">Argentina</label>
            </div>

            <div class="option-2">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="Norway*" name="category"/>
                <label for="Norway">Norway</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="selected-2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="Planejava.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in a website with two drop-downs, but only the first one actually changes to the active state when clicked. When I add the active class to the second drop down manually in the html, it opens up, so I'm thinking there is an issue with the javascript. I'm sure I am making an obvious mistake. Also I know it's silly to have a replicate of every css section just for the second drop-down, but I tried using the comma strategy and that didn't work, so I'm trying everything.

Comment: I put this in a code editor (codepen.io to be specific) and it works as expected.

Comment: You could simplify your css by using the same classes for both groups, but having a different `id` attribute to target in the script for example.

Comment: I converted your code to a runnable SO snippet, without changes, and it works fine.

Comment: it seems to be working as expected for both your dropdowns!

Comment: Thanks everyone! Restarting my computer made it start working for some reason haha. Appreciate all the advice.